# Exchange Web Services GetAttachment will not stream to disk

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are using Exchange Web Services from java (jaxws). Here's the issue. To get an attachment, you execute the GetAttachment soap call (logical enough :) ). Here's the problem: the entire attachment is returned (with no access to attachment size) in a base64 packet tucked deep inside a soap response along with other info. As a result the entire attachment contents is buffered into memory. With potentially 2GB attachments, this can get the entire java client to blow up out of memory.

There appears to be no way to get just pieces of attachments from EWS. MTOM, etc does not appear to be supported. In short there appears to be no provisions in EWS for streaming.

The only way around this situation would seem to be a very low level proxy to intercept these calls, and stream the contents to disk, replacing it with a "marker flag" to the file on disk. But there appears to be no elegant way to do this?

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have succeeded through a SOAP MessageHandler. Right now it streams everything to disk, and the caller must interpret the content as the disk uri. We believe it could be improved. Nonetheless, it IS possible to do

Comment: Another option is to use the Managed API for Java which basically streams this too. Be aware it is RIDDLED with bugs though

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there is no way to stream the contents directly to disk.

Comment: There is ALWAYS a way. Some are more painful than others.